# add class to option in select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Based on the value of an option would that be possible to add a class to an option?

So if i have this:

```
   <select class="rubrique" name="ctl00">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
```

i'll get that:

```
<select class="rubrique" name="ctl00">
        <option class="" value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option class="1" value="1">1</option>
        <option class="2" value="1">1</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, very easily, using the callback signature of [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/):

```
$('.rubrique option').addClass(function() {
    return this.value;
});
```

Comment: Nice one. Note to self: *Every* time you start to write `each`, think about what you're really trying to do. Every time. 'Cause nine times out of 10, you can just use the thing you actually want to use (e.g., `addClass` in this case).

Comment: I just also wanted to point out that although it may work, technically, a class may not start with (or just be) a number according to the W3C standards (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters)  "In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit."  Therefore, I would change the middle line to something like `return 'option-'+this.value;`

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.rubrique > option').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass($(this).val());
});
```

Edit: I am not sure if .val() is 100% correct here, you could also use this:

```
$('.rubrique > option').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

Comment: *"I am not sure if .val() is 100% correct here"* Perhaps not, but `this.value` is, and has the advantage of avoiding that redundant `$(this)`.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to add class to an option:

```
$("#IdOfSelect  option[value='" + valueOfSelect + "']").addClass('hidden');
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's the purpose to style a particular option element, you could consider this approach as well:

```
.rubrique option[value="2"]{
     background: yellow;
}
```