# if option in select has class then add class

Tags: jquery

is there a way to do: **if options have class 1 and 2 then add class A** in jQuery?

So this  :

```
<select class="rubrique" name="ctl00">
            <option class="" value="" selected="selected"></option>
            <option class="1" value="1">1</option>
            <option class="2" value="2">2</option>
           </select>
```

would give me that:

```
 <select class="rubrique" name="ctl00">
            <option class="" value="" selected="selected"></option>
            <option class="1 A" value="1">1</option>
            <option class="2 A" value="2">2</option>
           </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want both class 1 and class 2 to be present:

```
$('.rubrique > .1.2').addClass('A');
```

You can chain the class-selector `.` and class-names to find elements with both.

Otherwise, as noted, if you want to add class A to both:

```
$('.rubrique > .1, .rubrique > .2').addClass('A');
```

Is what's needed.

With thanks @T.J. Crowder for pointing out my original mis-reading of the question example.

Comment: Your selector will only find elements with *both* `1` and `2`. @user's example data makes it clear he wants *either*, rather than *both*.

Comment: It would indeed, I took his request "if options have class 1 and 2 then add class A" literally. Oops.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( '.rubrique > option.1, .rubrique > option.2' ).addClass( 'A' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd've thought the answers to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754114/add-class-to-option-in-select) would've shown you how to get there pretty easily.

Basically, you just change the selector a bit, and since your class no longer varies based on the element, you don't need to use a function, just a string:

```
$('.rubrique option.1, .rubrique option.2').addClass("A");
```

...but note that "1" and "2" are invalid [CSS class names](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier).

Further reading:

- [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

...and just generally the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/).

Comment: I realise that '1' and '2' are invalid `class` names for html 4, as is also true for the `id`, but as `id` is allowed a numeric first-character (possibly only-character) in html5, is the same not true of the `class`?

Comment: the 1 and 2 are just an example :) sorry to bother with simple question :)

Comment: @David: HTML doesn't define a valid CSS class name. CSS does. HTML defines valid values for the `class` attribute, but that's not the same thing. :-) HTML and CSS also (now) have very different definitions for valid `id` values. HTML5 [allows just about anything but spaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute), whereas CSS is [much more restrictive](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). Future versions of CSS may open it up (although allowing, say, `.` would require having an escaping mechanism for style rules), but the current rules are clear.

Comment: Thanks; it's just one of the mysteries of the css/html world that I occasionally wonder about... :)

Comment: @David: :-) Yes, it's great fun, isn't it? HTML5, HTML4.01, and CSS all have different rules for valid `id` values. Ah, well...

Comment: Eh, it keeps some of us in jobs... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery("option").each(function(){
   if(jQuery(this).hasClass("1") && jQuery(this).hasClass("2")) {
      jQuery(this).addClass("A");
   }
});
```